# How to replace the last characters depending on the count of another textbox

Tags: vba, ms-access, replace, ms-access-forms

I am trying to create a custom Autonumber for a registration form.

In my form I have an unbound textbox (`txtposition`) that gets the current record number. This number is the actual record number. If I have 10 records and I am at the last record it will display as 10.

I have another text box (`txtref`) with a default value as `0000`. What I need to get is the count of `txtposition` (if 10 means 2 and 100 means 3) and replace `txtref` from `0000` to `0010` or `0100` depending on the count of `txtposition`.

I already have another unbound textbox which will concatenate the results if required. I am trying to get this done in a query with:

```sql
spacepos: InStr([Forms]![Jobsheet]![Text516],"0000")
```

```sql
FN: Left([Forms]![Jobsheet]![Text516],[spacepos])
```

I know this will require a combination of `INSTR`, `LEN`, `RIGHT` or `LEFT` and surely `REPLACE` functions.

My knowledge of coding is too basic but I am able to follow.

The code used for getting the current record number for `txtposition`:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Current()
    On Error GoTo err_form_current

    Dim rst As Recordset
    Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
    rst.Bookmark = Me.Bookmark
    Me.txtPosition = rst.AbsolutePosition + 1

exit_form_current:
    Set rst = Nothing
    Exit Sub

err_form_current:
    If Err = 3021 Then 'no current record
        Me.txtPosition = rst.RecordCount + 1
    Else
        MsgBox Error$, 16, "Error in Form_Current()"
    End If
    Resume exit_form_current
End Sub
```

Comment: Just save a normal number then use formatting to display with leading zeros. `Format(10,"0000")` will display as 0010.

Comment: @June7 thank you very much, nice and simple. Exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save a normal number then use formatting to display with leading zeros. `Format(10,"0000")` will display as string 0010. No VBA required. Can even format an autonumber field using Format property or Format function. However, if cannot allow gaps in sequence, then an autonumber might not meet your requirements.

Comment: Yes i know of formatting the autonumber to display as 0000 but i dont use that method as, if a user adds a record then decides to cancel the new record without saving it will skip a sequence. For that reason i use the current record number.